# How to check if a window.locaton is successful loaded using JavaScript in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

How to check if a window.locaton is successful loaded?
I would like to open a chrome snippet to redirect to a new URL and get the new URL link using console.log.

```
var long_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
var long_url1 = "https://google.com/";
window.location.replace(long_url);
//How to get new URL link "https://stackoverflow.com/"?
window.location.replace(long_url1);
//How to get new URL link "https://google.com/" again?
```

Answer (score 0):

To get current page URL try

```
window.location.href
```

More precise info

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only (/path/example.html)
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL (https://example.com/path/example.html)
var origin   = window.location.origin;   // Returns base URL (https://example.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.href to get current URL. So you can write:

```
var long_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
var long_url1 = "https://google.com/";
window.location.replace(long_url);
console.log(window.location.href);
window.location.replace(long_url1);
console.log(window.location.href);
```

To see the console logs even after redirecting to new URL you can go to inspect -> console -> settings -> check Preserve log. By doing so it will help you see all the console logs before or after redirection
[Check this image for viewing console settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWIFn.png)

Comment: How can I get this in console?
Navigated to https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
Navigated to https://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com/

Comment: To see the console logs even after redirecting to new URL you can go to inspect -> console -> settings -> check Preserve log. By doing so it will help you see all the console logs before or after redirection.